# Does there exist a dense subset $\ X\ $ of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ and a real number $\ a\neq 0\ $ such that $\{\ x+a:\ x\in X\ \} =\mathbb{R}\setminus X\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

Does there exist a dense subset $\ X\ $ of $\ \mathbb{R},\ $ and a real number $\ a\neq 0\ $ such that $\ \{\ x+a:\ x\in X\ \} = \mathbb{R}\setminus X\ ?$

Clearly our set $\ X\ $ must be totally disconnected and uncountable on every interval in order for $\ X\ $ to exist.

But I'm actually not sure on the answer to this question, and find it hard to give even a heuristic argument as to why the answer should be negative or affirmative. Maybe it has something to do with the Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: Why must it be uncountable on every interval?

Comment: The stiulation that $a\ne0$ seems redundant.

Comment: You guys are both right. I think my brain was malfunctioning for this question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$X=\{ x \in \mathbb R : \lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is odd}\}\mathbin{\triangle}  \mathbb Q = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}\,\Bigl([2n,2n+1)\cap\mathbb Q\Bigr) \cup \Bigl([2n+1,2n+2) \setminus \mathbb Q\Bigr) $$

This works for $a=1$. Scale it by your favorite $a$ if you want a different one.

(This $X$ is countable on every other unit interval, by the way).

Comment: Yeah, this makes my question look silly, which I guess it is. It felt to me like my question was more difficult than this answer suggests, but I guess it isn't...

Comment: Of course, if the OP wants $X$ to be uncountable on every interval, that can be arranged. You ccan partition $\mathbb R$ into two sets which are both uncountable (in fact have positive measure) in every interval, you can use one of those instead of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: If it makes you feel better, the _first_ edition of this answer was equally silly.