# Does $\exists\ X\subset [0,1],\ a\neq 0,b\in\mathbb{R},\ $ such that $\ (Y:=) \{ ax+b: x\in X \} \cap X = \emptyset;\ X\cup Y = [0,1]\ $ or $(0,1)\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

If $ X\subset [0,1],\ a\neq 0,b,\in\mathbb{R} $ then define$\ Y:= \{ax+b: x\in X \}.$

> Does there exist $X\subset [0,1],\ a,b\in\mathbb{R},\ $ such that $\ Y
>  \cap X = \emptyset;\ X\cup Y = [0,1]\ $ or $(0,1)\ ?$

If the question was to make $X\cup Y = [0,1)\ $ then $ X = \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $ will do, with $a=1, b = \frac{1}{2}.$

But if the question is to make $X\cup Y = [0,1]\ $ or $X\cup Y = (0,1)\ $ then I am not sure how to do it/ if it can be done.

This question made me think of [my question from a few months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227721/does-there-exist-a-dense-subset-x-of-mathbbr-and-a-real-number), but I don't see how alternating between rationals and irrationals helps with this question. For $X\cup Y = (0,1),\ $ can we arctan the function in Troposphere's answer to that question? I don't think that works.

Comment: What's the topology part of the question?

Comment: It's to do with the topological structure of $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: How does it do that?

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: @copper.hat:But nobody says $X$ is an interval. (In fact you've shown it can't be - but my intuition says that we'll be dealing with non-measurable sets if it's at all possible.

Comment: Yes, I misread. Nothing to see here.

Comment: @Jakobian for example, one part of a proof could be that: if $X$ exists then $X$ can have no: isolated points, closed sets, open sets, etc. Are these things not related to topology? I thought they were.

Comment: If we let $a$ be $0$, $Y$ becomes the set $\{b\}$, so for any $b\in[0,1]$, we can let $X$ be $[0,1]\setminus \{b\}$. - Note that contrary to me initial though (mentioned above) the sets are measurable.

Comment: @AdamRubinson but the question doesn't include anything topological, this is more set theory than topology

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity question edited to rule out $a=0.$ Jakobian - The question doesn't have any mention of topology, but the answers surely will have something to do with it.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity has an answer.

Comment: @Jakobian I suppose any non-trivial solution (that is discounting mine) will involve some topology, so I find the tag relevant.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity The answer to the previous question (cited in the current one) didn't include any topology, this is just speculation

Comment: @Jakobian Yes, but my speculation is that this question is sufficiently different and that any non-trivial answer (OP has ruled out my "solution" in an edit, formulation is just to protect my guess against other trivial cases) will involve the topology on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Even if so, the question itself has nothing a priori to do with topology. For a question there can be different methods of solving it using different approaches, even if one solution uses an approach from topology, this is not enough to assure that the tag "general-topology" is appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: Note that $(0,1)=\biguplus_{n=1}^\infty[2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)})$. How does this help you (e.g. for $a=2$,$b=0$)?

Comment: @PhoemueX Cute.

Comment: @Phowmeux ah so it’s very simple for $(0,1)$ then. I didn’t think of that.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested in the comments, this is easy enough to do for $(0,1)$ by taking $b=0$ and $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[a^{-2n},a^{-2n+1})$ for any $a>1$.  However, it is not possible for $[0,1]$.

To prove this, suppose such an $X$, $a$ and $b$ existed for $[0,1]$, and let $f(x)=ax+b$.  Note first that $f$ cannot have a fixed point in $[0,1]$, since then that fixed point could not be in either $X$ or $Y$.  It then follows that $f(x)-x$ has the same sign on all of $[0,1]$.  It follows then that for any $x\in[0,1]$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n(x)\not\in[0,1]$.  Indeed, if no such $n$ exists, $(f^n(x))$ would be a monotone bounded sequence which would converge to a point of $[0,1]$.  By continuity, this limit would be a fixed point of $f$ in $[0,1]$, which cannot exist.

Now for each $x\in[0,1]$, let $e(x)$ be the least $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n(x)\not\in[0,1]$.  If $e(x)=1$ then $x$ cannot be in $X$ (since $f(x)\not\in[0,1]$) so $x\in Y$.  If $e(x)=2$ then $e(f(x))=1$ so $f(x)\in Y$ and thus $x\in X$.  Continuing similarly, we see that $X$ must consist of all $x\in[0,1]$ such that $e(x)$ is even and $Y$ must consist of all $x\in[0,1]$ such that $e(x)$ is odd.

As mentioned above, we know the sign of $f(x)-x$ is constant on $[0,1]$; let us assume $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ (the other case is similar, and indeed equivalent by conjugating everything by $x\mapsto 1-x$).  Note that this implies $a>0$, since $f(0)\leq 1<f(1)$, so $f$ is increasing.  This also implies $f^{-1}(0)\not\in[0,1]$, so we must have $0\in X$, so $e(0)$ is even.  Note that $f^{e(0)-1}(f(0))=f^{e(0)}(0)>1$.  So by continuity, for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, $x=f(0)-\epsilon$ will still satisfy $f^{e(0)-1}(x)>1$.  Also, $f^{e(0)-2}(x)<f^{e(0)-2}(f(0))\leq 1$, and thus $e(x)=e(0)-1$ is odd for such $x$, so $x\in Y$.  But this means $f^{-1}(x)\in X$, which is impossible since $f^{-1}(x)<0$.

Here's a more conceptual way to think about this argument.  You can split $[0,1]$ into orbits of $f$.  Each of these orbits is a a finite increasing sequence of points, that ends when applying $f$ one more time would go above $1$ and begins when applying $f^{-1}$ one more time would go below $0$.  In order to be able to partition these orbits into $X$ and $Y$ with $f(X)=Y$, each orbit needs to contain an even number of elements, so every other element of the orbit goes in each set, starting with $X$ and ending with $Y$.  But now consider the orbit of $0$.  If you shift the orbit down a tiny bit, then the bottom point $0$ of the orbit will leave $[0,1]$, but none of the other points of the orbit will (and no new point will enter $[0,1]$ at the top).  This will give an orbit with one fewer element than the orbit of $0$, which is a contradiction since all the orbits need to have even size.

(In the case of an open interval $(0,1)$, you can do a similar argument *assuming* all the orbits are finite.  For instance, you could take the orbit of $f(0)$ and shift it up a tiny bit to get an orbit with one more element.  This shows that any example for $(0,1)$ must have an infinite orbit.  As argued in the second paragraph above, this implies $f$ has a fixed point in $[0,1]$, which must then be at $0$ or $1$ since there cannot be a fixed point in $(0,1)$.  This shows that the example of the first paragraph is essentially the *only* possible example for $(0,1)$.  To be precise, it is the only possible example where $0$ is the fixed point of $f$ and $a>1$ (as again, once you fix $f$, the set $X$ is uniquely determined by the parity of $e(x)$).  Taking $0<a<1$ instead just means replacing $f$ with its inverse and swapping the sets $X$ and $Y$.  And, there are also examples with $1$ as the fixed point instead of $0$, obtained from these examples by conjugating by $x\mapsto 1-x$.)